# Xamarin BroadcastReceiver OnReceive GetResultExtras is empty

Tags: xamarin

I'm doing an Android application with Visual Studio 2022 and Xamarin and find that `OnReceive` method receives nothing. I've followed some examples I found but it doesn't work. The code I use is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionGetLanguageDetails);
    SendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new LanguageDetailsChecker(), null, Result.Ok, null, null);
  }

}

public class LanguageDetailsChecker : BroadcastReceiver
{

  public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {

    Bundle results = GetResultExtras(true);

    if (results.ContainsKey(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSupportedLanguages))
    {

       Some code

    }

  }

}
```

I expect results to return not empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from `GetResultExtras(true);` on method `OnReceive` of `LanguageDetailsChecker`, you need to set the `Bundle` parameter when you send Broadcast.

Please refer to the following code:

```
private void Button_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionGetLanguageDetails);
            //method 2
            intent.PutExtra("mykey","test_value");


            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("key", "bundle_string");
            //see the last parameter
            SendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new LanguageDetailsChecker(), null, Result.Ok, null, bundle);
        }
```

Then we can receive the passed data as follows:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { RecognizerIntent.ActionGetLanguageDetails })]
public class LanguageDetailsChecker : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context? context, Intent? intent)
    {

        if (intent == null)
            return;

        Bundle bundle = GetResultExtras(true);
        if (bundle == null)
            return;
        string stringvalue = bundle.GetString("key");


        //method 2
        String value = intent.GetStringExtra("mykey");

    }
}
```

**Note:**

You can also pass data by using following code

```
  intent.PutExtra("mykey","test_value");
```

And get data on method `OnReceive` of your `BroadcastReceiver` as follows:

```
 String value = intent.GetStringExtra("mykey");
```

Comment: It does not return empty, but does not contain the languges list I expected. It returns "bundle_string" or "test_value" instead.